# Move an element in relative layout to absolute edge of the screen

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Is it possible to move a button or any other element in relative layout to the absolute edge of the sreen? If I drag a certain element to the edge of the layout, eclipse will automatically place it a few dp away from the edge. It'll basically just create a small space between a button and the end of the creen. Is it possible to bypass that?

I know buttons aren't meant to be that close to the edge of the screen anyway, but I need it for a certain thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal button has a little padding by default, because the buttons backgroundimage is a 9-patch image with padding left, right and on bottom. That's why you see the space between button and screen.

To solve this you can use a custom button. For example change the backgroundimage of button like this `android:background="@drawable/image"`.